# Merge dictionaries by key with dictionary names as subkeys

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I am looking for a short and pythonic way to merge two (three, n) dictionaries by key. There are couple of questions on merging or appending dictionaries, but here I am looking for appending a value to another value when their keys equal. All my dictionaries have exactly the same set of keys.

```
dic0 = {'Amsterdam': 0, 'Berlin': 5, 'London': 7}
dic1 = {'Amsterdam': 1, 'Berlin': 7, 'London': 8}
```

Desired output:

```
combined_dict = {'Amsterdam': {'dic0': 0, 'dic1':1}, 'Berlin': {'dic0': 5, 'dic1':7}, 'London': {'dic0': 7, 'dic1':8}}
```

I could achieve this with

```
combined_dict = {}
for key in dic0.keys():
    combined_dict[key] = {}
    combined_dict[key]['dic0'] = dic0[key]
    combined_dict[key]['dic1'] = dic1[key]
```

but this seems is far from easy to extend. As a first step, I even failed to get the name of the dictionaries.

Comment: Yes. See last sentence of the first paragraph.

Comment: Why use 'dic0', 'dic1' at all? Or even use internal dictionaries? Why not use a simpler representation, like: `combined_dict = {'Amsterdam': [0, 1], 'Berlin': [5, 7], 'London': [7 8]}`

Comment: Because I want to print it to a csv *with* proper fieldnames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work with a list of dictionary names, for example `dicts = ['dic0', 'dic1']`:

```
combo = {k: {i: eval(i)[k] for i in dicts} for k in eval(dicts[0]).keys()}
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? My code is perfect, and people care to downvote without explanation.

Comment: Not my downvote, but maybe people don't like the `eval`

Comment: The downvote was before I added that in, but honestly it's the only way to use the variable names as strings.

Comment: I like your answer and I can share you grief about uncommented downvotes.